# Applying conditions in bind in view

Tags: extjs, bind, formula

How to apply conditions in bind?

In view let

`{
xtype : 'label',
    bind : {
         text : '{//--- set text as per the condition }',
         hidden : '{//should be true if 'param' in VM is 1 or 2 else should 
                    be false}'
     }
}`

in view model, 'param' is a data variable. If value of

param=1, text should be one,

param=2, text should be two,

param=3, text should be three.

Is this possible without formula by applying conditions directly in view?

Comment: No, you need to use a formula.

Comment: Another option you may have is, to bind the state to variable in the config. Bind the state to that config, then change it on the update function hook, depending on state

Comment: You can find formulas that implement a "state" changing in [this example](http://extjs.eu/ext-examples/#complex-data-binding-5).

Answer (score -2):

```
{
    xtype : 'label',
    bind : 
    {
        text : '{textVal}'==0?'Test':'TEST1234',
        hidden : ('{param}'==1 || '{param}'==2)?true:false
    }
}
```

In the associated viewModel, if one has the property `param` in data config, then one can use it for binding along with condition checks as mentioned above. If the `param` value is being changed dynamically, (i.e, `this.getViewModel().setData('param', 1))` then still the code will work in hiding the component dynamically. The same applies with the other config, `viewModel -> data:{textVal:0,param:1}`. If one has an object inside the data, like `data:{ config:{ textVal:0 }, param:1 }`, One can use `bind:{ text:'{config.textVal}' //along with ur condition check }`

Comment: Add explanations to your answers and format your answer accordingly.

Comment: @Adam: Explanation -> Say in the associated viewModel, if u have the property "param" in data config, then u can use it for binding along with condition checks as mentioned above. 
if my param value is being changed dynamically,  (i.e, this.getViewModel().setData('param', 1)) then still my code will work in hiding the component dynamically.
Same applys with the other config.
 viewModel -> data:{textVal:0,param:1} 
if u have object inside the data, like 
data:{
  config:{
     textVal:0
  },
  param:1
}, You can use bind:{
   text:'{config.textVal}' //along with ur condition check
}

Comment: I don't understand how can expressions in the answer happen to work. Any `==` comparison would be always evaluated to false by javascript engine before being passed to extjs bind logic.

Comment: This doesn't work.